# How do i restrict the players movement without stopping them from moving entirely

Tags: python, pygame

i am trying to do some basic collision detection in pygame, so far I have it set up so if one sprite comes into contact with another they both stop, what I want to know is if my player hits the sprite how can I allow it to go any other way apart from further in the sprite.

How I have it set up now I just have a function that detects whether or not they have collided which changes a global variable that disables movement altogether.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Please describe the desired behavior precisely. And show us your code (a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

Answer (score 0):

Sprites should have a `xVel` and `yVel` variables. These variables will change the `x` and `y` variables every frame. The sprite is then drawn to the screen at the respective `x` and `y` variables.

```
class Sprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.xVel = 0
        self.yVel = 0

        self.x = 100
        self.y = 100

        # Continue method

    def update(self):
        self.x += xVel
        self.y += yVel

        # Continue method
```

Here's what the sprite collision handling code would look like.

```
if sprite1.yVel == 0 and sprite2.yVel == 0:
    # This is when the sprites are not travelling up or down the y axis
    sprite1.xVel = -sprite1.xVel
    sprite2.xVel = -sprite2.xVel

if sprite1.xVel == 0 and sprite2.xVel == 0:
    # This is when the sprites are not travelling left or right on the x           
    # axis
    sprite1.yVel = -sprite1.yVel
    sprite2.yVel = -sprite2.yVel
```

This code is for 4-way movement. Setting the `xVel` variable equal to `-xVel` will make it travel the opposite direction. The same applies to the `yVel` variable. There is no need to change any global variables as long as you are using objects.

Also when a player is traveling left or right then `yVel == 0`. If the player is traveling up or down then `xVel == 0`.

Please note the speed of the sprite's movement will vary according to the framerate. The way you fix this is to use deltatime which is a concept for another question.

Hope this helped!